# Powershell pull string from HTML with regex

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way to regex basically a multi lined string.

This will always start with:

```
 <table class="MsoNormalTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="900" style="width:675.0pt;border:solid black 1.0pt">
```

and end with

```
</table>
```

A link to sample HTML can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/MtSa06ue

I tried

```
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="900" style="width:675.0pt;border:solid black 1.0pt">.*</table>
```

Thinking `.*` would grab until `</table>` but it does not...any help would be appreciated

Comment: replaced `[` with `<` and proper markup so it displays ;)

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be causing your issue when you don't show the code you use for processing the data. Most likely your input is not a single string, but an array of lines. Regular expressions operate on one string at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would like to see a regex answer as well, but i was able to get some results with this. it may be of use to you. instead of a multi-line string, i split it on linefeed to have an array of strings.

```
$text = @'
<html>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="900" style="width:675.0pt;border:solid black 1.0pt">
...
</table>
</html>
'@.Split("`n")

$inside = 0
$result = $text | % {
    if ($_.Trim() -eq '<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="900" style="width:675.0pt;border:solid black 1.0pt">') {
        $inside = 1
        Write-Output $_
    } elseif ($inside -eq 1 -and $_.Trim() -eq '</table>') {
        $inside = 0
        Write-Output $_
    } elseif ($inside -eq 1) {
        Write-Output $_
    }
}
$result
```

Comment: This actually may work better than regex for my application, thank you very much Anthony!